# Calling stored procedure with table-valued parameter returns error

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers

I have a class that I converts into a datatable so I can pass it as a TVP to a stored procedure.

The class contains just primitive types such as `int`, `string`, `DateTime` and `Guid`. After converting to a datatable, I call the stored procedure as follows:

```
var ids = connection.Query<int>("create_records", new { records }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

On monitoring with SQL Server Profiler, I can see that the SQL is created correctly and I can execute this same SQL in T-SQL successfully.

However, when executing the stored procedure from code, I get the following error:

> XML parsing: Row 1, Character 2112, invalid name character.

The exception is:

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteReaderWithFlagsFallback(IDbCommand cmd, Boolean wasClosed, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryImpl>d__125`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType)
```

The stored procedure inserts the TVP records into a couple of different tables, and at the end does the following:

```
SELECT id FROM @insertedRecords;
```

where `@insertedRecords` is a table-type with just 1 column (int) and is filled with the id's of the inserted records from the `MERGE` statement. Executing the stored procedure from within `T-SQL` with the same data passed by code works fine and records are inserted as expected.

**UPDATE**

After further debugging, the problem lies in an audit trigger associated with the table. An excerpt of the modified trigger is:

```
declare @xml xml;

set  @xml = (SELECT '' as 'id/old', ISNULL(i.[id], '') as 'id/new'
FROM inserted AS i FOR XML PATH('inserts'));

insert into _temp select @xml;
```

Note: The select includes all the table's columns and not just the one. '_temp' is just a table with one column (`xml`).

The original problem that the trigger fails when inserting records from code still stands.

Is there an alternative way to output the columns in xml format without using `FOR XML` or at least disabling parsing?

Comment: Try passing the `records` parameter as `DataTable`.

Comment: @Lucero Yes. records is the datatable converted from a List<T>

Comment: Post the full exception, including its call stack. You can get it with `Exception.ToString()`. That does not look like a Dapper error. Does the underlying table have a field named `XML-Analysis`? What does the stored procedure do?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Exception added. No I don't have a field name `Xml-Analysis`. The stored procedure just takes the `TVP` and inserts records in a couple of different tables. The stored procedure works fine in `T-SQL.`

Comment: You haven't shown us the C# that makes `records`, you haven't shown us the TSQL for the stored procedure `create_records`.

Comment: @Jodrell I use FastMember to convert the list to a datatable. the stored procedure works fine in T-SQL. No errors there.